# Radian Measure given the arc is 3/7 diameter

Tags: trigonometry

The question is what is the radian measure of a central angle of a circle if the subtended arc has a length that is $3/7$ of the length of the diameter.

I reasoned as follows:

if $1/2$ the diameter = 1 radian, then $3/7$ of a diameter would be $6/7$ of a radian.  Is this correct reasoning?

Comment: Perfectly correct. That's simply  the rule of three.

Comment: Wow, never heard of the rule of three.  Can you say more about that?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I know that rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$L=\frac 37 D=\frac 67 R$$

the measure of the angle is

$\frac{6}{7} $ radians.